# How to find the number of splits of second array to create first array?

Tags: java

Let's have two arrays that has same elements and difference order such as,

```
arrayOne={1,5,7,8,6}

arrayTwo={5,7,1,8,6}
```

then I want to find the number of sets of second array to create the order of first array.as an example,

we can divide `arrayTwo` to `{5,7}, {1}, {8,6}` then arranging these three parts can create first array like,

```
{1},{5,7},{8,6}
```

in this case number of sets are equal to 3.

So how should I write a code to return the number of sets of this problem in java?

Comment: have you attempted to write any code??

Comment: yes but i was stucked.I haven't a good idea of this algorithm

Comment: @Tarin Show us some work? What did you try?

Comment: You should not be writing code. You should be developing an algorithm. The two processes are different.

Comment: Can the same number occur more than once in the array?

Comment: Check if the whole array matches, if not then remove the right most number and check if the new set matches, continue until you get a match. Then start over but with a set starting with the number to the right of the last number in the previous match.

Comment: I just write a pseudocode @Nikhil in that case i firstly find the matching element in second array for first value of first array.then keep a count and keep searching for mismatching.but it is not the answer

Comment: there are no duplicate numbers @Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without duplicate numbers in the array, you start at beginning of second array, locate that first number (`5`) in the first array, find how many numbers match after that (2), and you have your first sub-array (`[5,7]`).

Then repeat starting with the next number in the second array (`1`), until all done.

*Example*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(findSets(
            new int[] {1,5,7,8,6},
            new int[] {5,7,1,8,6})));
}
static int[][] findSets(int[] ref, int[] values) {
    List<int[]> sets = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0, len; i < values.length; i += len) {
        // Find value in 'ref' array
        int j = 0;
        while (ref[j] != values[i])
            j++;
        // Find length of matching sub-array
        len = 1;
        while (i + len < values.length && j + len < ref.length && ref[j + len] == values[i + len])
            len++;
        // Add to result
        sets.add(Arrays.copyOfRange(values, i, i + len));
    }
    return sets.toArray(new int[sets.size()][]);
}
```

*Output*

```
[[5, 7], [1], [8, 6]]
```